# Access localhost site using a valid url

Tags: iis-7, localhost, hosts

I've done this before, but I've forgotten it.   Basically, to mimic an actual website on my local machine, I did some stuff so I could access my localhost site using a valid url. I've now forgotten how to do this. :(

I remember it had something to do with IIS site bindings and the hosts file.  Could anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add your `127.0.0.1` IP address on your host files with the host you'd like to mimic.

The file is located at `%windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`

and the format is:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.you.want.to.mimic
```

You must edit this file as administrator.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that out.  However, just wondering: do we need to add bindings inside of IIS?

Comment: So, it appears you do need to configure Bindings. I got hit with tons of errors because services on my site were trying to access the mimic domain, while iss didn't know it existed.